# javascript return statement does'nt seem to do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

I have a short piece of code that I meant to implement into a page;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("h1").hide();
  $("h2").hide();
  $("h3").hide();
});

$(function() {

  $("h1").delay(2000).show().animate({

    marginTop: "40%"
  }, 1000);
  return;
});
```

Well, I guess after glancing again I have two questions. 
First question: should the 'return' statement be used at the end of every
function to indicate the function is complete?
Second Question: 
And if it is complete, and the layout of page has been manipulated by the function shouldn't the styling and anything else that was changed return to it's original state? mine did not. and actually stopped everything from proceeding after this function. with or without the 'return' statement.

Comment: I dont think u need a return statement but u need to specify when  u intend to call your function for eg: on click or page load or hover etc

Comment: thank you and I thought the initial 'document ready' was the call. Basically , On page load.